Karate match with condition
I know about conditional assertion and also the discussions around match. My case seems to me to be not as complicated as discussed in the last question.
So what I want to achieve is to match things with condition but like assertion, shown in the first question:
match (result == []) || (each result contains { pass: true })

Just want to check if my result contains something only if it is not empty. Previously match each result contains { pass: true } was returning true even if the result was empty, but after updating to the latest 1.5.0.RC3 version it started to work differently.

If you want the old behavior, just use configure: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2364
